# Matching documents where multiple fields match in an array of objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an array of objects inside a document in ES

I want to only match documents where 2 fields inside an object (within the array) match.

My problem is this. Say I have 3 documents (outer document removed) where I have an array of objects such as

```
                       // Doc 1
                        "questionAnswers": [
               
                        {
                            "question": "First yes no question",
                            "answer": "Yes"
                        },
                        {
                            "question": "Second yes no question",
                            "answer": "No"
                        }
                    ]


                       // Doc 2
                        "questionAnswers": [
               
                        {
                            "question": "First yes no question",
                            "answer": "No"
                        },
                        {
                            "question": "Second yes no question",
                            "answer": "No"
                        }
                    ]


                       // Doc 3
                        "questionAnswers": [
               
                        {
                            "question": "First yes no question",
                            "answer": "No"
                        },
                        {
                            "question": "Second yes no question",
                            "answer": "Yes"
                        }
                    ]
```

And my query is

```
{
"from": 0,
"size": 25,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
            {
                "match": {
                    "questionAnswers.question.keyword": "First yes no question"
                }
            },
            {
                    "match": {
                        "questionAnswers.answer": "Yes"
                    }
                
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I'm currently getting matches for documents 1 and 3. Whereas I only want the first document to match where question = First yes no question and answer = Yes

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `questionAnswers` field to be of [nested type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) so that each array object in it can be queried separately, and you can use [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-inner-hits.html) to get only matching document in the result.

Adding a working example with index mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "questionAnswers": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "questionAnswers",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "match": {
                "questionAnswers.question.keyword": "First yes no question"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "questionAnswers.answer": "Yes"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "score_mode": "avg",
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "68760699",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "questionAnswers": [
            {
              "question": "First yes no question",
              "answer": "Yes"
            },
            {
              "question": "Second yes no question",
              "answer": "No"
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "questionAnswers": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 0.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "68760699",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "questionAnswers",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 0.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "question": "First yes no question",           //note this
                    "answer": "Yes"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @David Billings please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolved your issue ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, yes this works as I need it to!