# Querying an Array of Object by matching UserID in a Collection of Documents Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

My query is actually similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68760699/matching-documents-where-multiple-fields-match-in-an-array-of-objects), except each Doc has differing SellerIDs per document.

I'd like to retrieve the Object if it has a matching SellerID. but you might suggest that we'd need to make separate Documents or Collections for each of those in order to query them.

Maybe that's something like `firestore.collection("orders").doc.where('productSellerID', '==', currentUser.SellerID)`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. What happens if you do `firestore.collection("orders").where('productSellerID', '==', currentUser.SellerID)` (without `doc`)? Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Currently trying now, its just Im working with legacy code thats kind of confusing to pass in. Will update

Comment: Using the query Frank van Puffelen provided are you getting any documents?

Comment: I will attempt this, although I have a feeling this might fail. I started working on batches. But I will update this post with that query when we get to it later today. Thanks so much for the help.